# Calling ASMX web service from PHP when Operations accept an Interface

Tags: c#, php, web-services, asmx

I have a .Net web service that has a method that accepts an Interface that I have written as a parameter. Let's call this interface ICustomer.

How would you call this method from PHP?

The method definition is

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string RegisterCustomer(ICustomer customer)
    {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX? WCF? Also, what doyou mean it accepts an interface? Show an example, please?

Comment: It's an ASMX webservice. What I mean is that the method accepts a class that implements the Interface I have created.

Comment: I don't believe you can pass an interface to an ASMX service at all. How do you call it from .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a StdClass on PHP with same attributes that in .NET.

ex:

```
<?php
$object = new stdClass();
$object->Name = "Test";
$object->LastName = "More tests";
$object->AnotherAttribute = "Abc";
...

$client = new SoapClient($url);
$client->__soapCall("MethodName", array('parameters' => array('customer' => $object));
...
?>
```

If I understand your question, is this.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP?

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $client->ICustomer($param);
```

Comment: Oh, if only it were this simple in practice.

Comment: Surely this should be $client->RegisterCustomer($param)? How would you construct $param in php?

Comment: indeed it should be  $client->RegisterCustomer($param).
$param is ordered or associative array.  eg 
$param['custimer_id']=1000;