# Can ASP.NET Webservice work on PHP Site?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I would like to know if ASP.NET Webservice can work on PHP Website or not?

Thank you.

Comment: yes. refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648999/calling-asmx-web-service-from-php-when-operations-accept-an-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once refer this site regarding consuming web services http://forums.asp.net/t/887892.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a webservice call from PHP site, it does not matter if the webservice is written in ASP.NET or JSP or any other language that support webservice because usually it uses XML data format to exchange data.